# htaccess request uri starts with http(s) redirect

Tags: .htaccess

if the request uri = / I want to let in the request

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: www.example.com\r\n
Accept: */*\r\n
Content-Type: text/html\r\n
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
Content-length: 0\r\n
\r\n
```

but if the request uri starts with http:// [OR] https://

```
GET http://www.baidu.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: www.baidu.com\r\n
Accept: */*\r\n
Content-Type: text/html\r\n
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
Content-length: 0\r\n
\r\n
```

I want it to 301 redirect to the requested uri (redirect to www.baidu.com in this example)

I have tried this in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^http://$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^https://$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

but when I tried to access www.example.com it went into a redirect loop

Comment: Are you certain that you want to send a 301? That's not going to be good for your web server. The attackers who do this will just hit you even harder.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ https?://[^\ ]+ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Where `THE_REQUEST` server variable is the initial request header. For example:

```
GET http://www.baidu.com/ HTTP/1.1
```

However, I doubt that this will work - or whether this is even possible. You are essentially redirecting to the *same URL* (potential redirect loop), back to a user-agent that has already constructed this malformed request. That same user-agent is likely to construct the same malformed request(?), if the redirect even occurs (because the URL-path hasn't actually changed).

I think you are better off rejecting such malformed requests in your server config, since I can't imagine they are legitimate requests anyway? For example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ https?://[^\ ]+ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Although there may be better ways than using mod_rewrite.

Answer (score -1):

Might have solved this with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} http:// [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} https:// [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You can only match forward proxy URLs if you also have `RewriteOptions AllowAnyURI` otherwise mod_rewrite will decline to do the match.